# How to use payU for money transfer for seller buyer android app?

Tags: android, paypal, e-commerce, payumoney, payu

I am working on an eCommerce android app. I have made seller and customer application. I want to use payU for payment. I want to know how money will be transferred from customer to seller. I will explain my problem by below example.

Suppose there are three sellers S1,S2,S3 and three customers C1,C2,C3. And each seller and customer have separate bank accounts. I want to integrate payU such that customers can directly pay to sellers bank account. I read the payU documentation but it only tells how to make a merchant account and then how to make payment into the merchant account. But I want to know how does other eCommerce app transfer money to there seller for whatever they sell. So Should I need to make merchant account for each seller or something else ?

Comment: I feel like changing merchants id dynamically while calling payment gateway may work...

Comment: @jagapathi Ok for that we will have to ask all sellers to make a merchant account and making merchant account is a long process. So do you think  apps like flipkart, amazon asks all sellers to make a open a new account ? I think there should be some way to link any account to payment gateway someway.